# Java Recursive food allocation

Tags: java, recursion

I have the following lists:

Animals     Food
Cat         Fish
Dog         Pork
            Beef
I would like to allocate food to the animals in as many different ways as possible like:

Each different animal and food combination will be stored in a map.

(Cat eats Fish, 
Dog eats Pork)

(Cat eats Fish, 
Dog eats Beef)

(Cat eats Pork, 
Dog eats Fish)

(Cat eats Pork, 
Dog eats Beef)

(Cat eats Beef, 
Dog eats Fish)

(Cat eats Beef, 
Dog eats Pork)

Finally all the maps will be put in a set and returned.

I am trying to use recursive function for the same and the following is how I tried it.. but am not able to get it right it right, so please help me to make it.

Thanks in advance!!!

```
private static Set<Map<Animal, Food>> eats(List<Animal> animal, List<Food> food) {
    Set<Map<Animal, Food>> returnSet = new HashSet<Map<Animal, Food>>();
    Map<Animal, Food> map = new HashMap<Animal, Food>();
    if (animal.size() == 0) {
        return null; // There is no animal to feed
    } else {
        animalLoop: for (int i = 0; i < animal.size(); i++) {
            foodLoop: for (int j = 0; j < food.size(); j++) {
                map.put(animal.get(i), food.get(j));
                food.remove(j);
                break venueLoop;
                }
            }
            animal.remove(i);
            returnSet.add(map);
        }

    }
    return returnSet.add(eats(animal, food));
}
```

Comment: An Animal eats foods, so your map should be: `Map<Animal, List<Food>>`. And another problem is you can not remove an element out of a list while it in use in a loop.

Comment: I see combinations missing.  Your cat and dog cannot both eat pork at the same time?

Comment: Thanks but I want the food to be finished if eaten by one animal. So other animals cannot get the same food.

Comment: @markspace. No if a food is eaten by one animal, it is finished and the other needs to eat another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working program for reference if we need to keep the method fingerprint and don not run a global visited tracking structure.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class SFO_Recursive {
    public enum Animal {
        CAT, DOG ;
    }
    public enum Food {
        FISH, BEEF, PORK ;
    }

    private static Set<Map<Animal, Food>> eats(List<Animal> animal, List<Food> food) {
        Set<Map<Animal,Food>> fleet = new HashSet();
        for (Animal a: animal){
            for (Food f: food){
                // Take a step with (a, f)
                List<Food> food_left = food.stream().filter(x -> !x.equals(f)).collect(Collectors.toList());
                List<Animal> animal_left = animal.stream().filter(x -> !x.equals(a)).collect(Collectors.toList());
                if (animal_left.isEmpty() || food_left.isEmpty()){
                    // Terminal state
                    fleet.add(new HashMap<Animal, Food>(){{put(a,f);}});
                }else {
                    eats(animal_left, food_left).stream().forEach(s -> {s.put(a, f); fleet.add(s); });
                }
            }
        }
        return fleet;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SFO_Recursive.eats(
            Arrays.asList(Animal.CAT, Animal.DOG),
            Arrays.asList(Food.BEEF, Food.FISH, Food.PORK)
        ).stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

The results are:

```
{CAT=BEEF, DOG=PORK}
{CAT=PORK, DOG=BEEF}
{CAT=BEEF, DOG=FISH}
{CAT=FISH, DOG=BEEF}
{CAT=FISH, DOG=PORK}
{CAT=PORK, DOG=FISH}
```

For recursive Depth-First-Search, there are two things to take care : terminal state condition, and, how to apply current step to a partial result from (future) terminal state(s).

If we have to keep the method fingerprint to return Set with inputs of two Lists. The terminal condition is the obvious empty list in either parameter to stop the search. To apply current step to a Set, we can loop all the Maps and just add the combination of new Animal obj and new Food obj to each one but rely on Set class to check whether unique Map is added. Without global tracking table, we can remove consumed elements from Animal and Food Lists to send the information to next state.

Java test equality by hashCode(). Map calculate hashCode as a sum of all entries and each entry takes hashCode(k) ^ hashCode(v). Every enum value has an unique hashCode by default. Therefore, it is okay to directly add Map elements.

Comment: Thank you very much. Exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. Here is something to get you started. It is NOT the whole solution, just a starting point. See comments and don't hesitate to ask if more clarifications are needed :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FoodAllocation{

    private static List<String> foods;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //use <Animal> instead of String
        List<String> animals = new ArrayList<>();
        animals.add("Dog");animals.add("Cat");

        //use Food> instead of String
        foods = new ArrayList<>();
        foods.add("Pork"); foods.add("Beef"); foods.add("Fish");

        allocateFood(animals, null);
    }

    //recursively allocate
    private static void allocateFood(List<String> animals, String eaten) {

        //you can't change a list while iterating  over it
        //so make a of animals
        List<String> animalsCopy = new ArrayList<>(animals);

        //loop over animals
        for (String animal : animals) {

            //loop over food
            for( String food : foods) {

                if(food.equals(eaten)) {
                    continue;
                }

                //(add to a collection instead of printing )
                System.out.println(animal +" eats " + food);
                animalsCopy.remove(animal);

                //food has been eaten 
                allocateFood(animalsCopy, food);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi c0der, thanks for your answer but I am still not able to proceed. After changing your line 60`code` foodsCopy = allocateFood(animalsCopy, foodsCopy); to animalsCopy = allocateFood(animalsCopy, foodsCopy);`code` I am able to get an allocation per run, but what I wanted was a list of all possible allocations. And the method should return the lists of "animal eats food"

Comment: The method returns `foodCopy` so it should be `foodsCopy = allocateFood(animalsCopy, foodsCopy);` . As I wrote this was not meant to be a complete solution, but something to get you started. You post is about "recursive" food allocation, but the code posted is not recursive. Is "recursive solution" part of the requirements ?

Comment: Thanks and yes I wanted to try it using recursion.

Comment: And when I use foodCopy, I am getting three allocations instead of two (for two animals)

Comment: I edited the code. I think it gets you close to what you are trying to achieve.